# Differential Equation in Complex Plane and Parametric Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, complex

I would like to solve $dx/dt=\sqrt{1 + (I x)^3}$, where x is complex, for some initial condition like $1 - 5 I$ and plot the imaginary part of the solution versus the real part. (A somewhat similar problem was posted earlier in different topic)

I have used this code:

```
s = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1 +(I x[t])^3)^0.5, x[0] == 1 -5 I}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. s1], {t,0,10}]
```

and I have tried it for different initial points, the results are not satisfactory. I expect to obtain closed contours for every initial condition in the lower half plane of complex plane, excatly like this:
[image]

(As a side and not very important remark x plus, minus and zero are where the square root vanishes)

I appreciate if one could help me to fix it!

P.S.:

Can this problem be due to branch points?

Comment: Not using any boundary-condition I got with `DSolve[{x'[t] == (1 + (I x[t])^3)^0.5}, x[t], t]` a rather sophisticated solution involving the inverse of `Hypergeometric2F1`. At this point I got stuck.

Comment: Solution provided at [258180](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/258185/1063).

Answer (score 5):

The closed contours are indeed difficult to produce in a `ParametricPlot` because the parametrization in terms of `t` doesn't allow you to follow a single closed curve beyond the singularity of `Sqrt[1 + (I x)^3]`. So it's fair to say that your issues are caused by the branch cuts. One can also see this by letting *Mathematica* do more of the work automatically, using `StreamPlot`. Streamlines in the `xy` plane are basically the equivalent of the contours in the complex plane that you're after.

```
With[{xMin = 3},
 StreamPlot[
  {Re[#], Im[#]} &[Sqrt[1 + (I (x + I y))^3]],
  {x, -xMin, xMin}, {y, -xMin, xMin}, 
  StreamPoints -> {{{0, 0}, Automatic, 6}}]
 ]
```

[image: one streamline]

This was created from a *single* `StreamPoint` as a starting condition for a stream line. You can see that we jump to different curves whenever a singularity of the derivative is crossed.

However, `StreamPlot` does produce something close to what you need if we let it choose the `StreamPoints` starting conditions automatically:

```
With[{xMin = 3},
 StreamPlot[
  {Re[#], Im[#]} &[Sqrt[1 + (I (x + I y))^3]],
  {x, -xMin, xMin}, {y, -xMin, xMin}]
 ]
```

[image: full plot]

Comment: I have the impression that `StreamPlot` is the better `NDSove`. I am impressed.