# Solving a complex-valued differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I am trying to solve $dx/dt=\sqrt{1+(ix)^{1.8}}$ for initial condition $x[0] =-0.9877 + i 0.1563$, where $x$ is a complex variable. I would like to plot the imaginary part of the solution versus the real part. I used `NDSolve` and `ParametricPlot`.

```
s1 = 
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == (1 + (I x[t])^1.8)^0.5, x[0] == -0.9877 + I 0.1563}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
    Method -> "ExplicitMidpoint", "StartingStepSize" -> 1/1000];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[x[t]], Im[x[t]]} /. s1], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

The result is wrong. I expect some kind of spiral. I think the problem is due to the fact that the graph crosses the branch cut which emanating from the origin. How can I fix it?

P.S.: I expect something like

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you add this to your earlier question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49189/245) and provide some feedback to my answer there, if it wasn't clear.

Comment: It was clear, but I was not looking for solving the DE with the direction fields. Eventually, I could solve the problem and obtained  contours in a difficult way, by plotting many parts of the solution in different regions and stick all of them together. But here is a different situation. Because of non-integerity of 1.8 in the power, a new kind of branch cut appears...

Comment: I tried also by direction fields approach, again the answer is nonsense!

Comment: Dealing with branch-cuts can be difficult and NDSolve doesn't do it automatically. I don't understand what you expect we can do about it.

Comment: I guessed it may be due to branch cut! I am confused.

Comment: Also StreamPlot does not give a correct answer.

Comment: I am not restricted to NDSolve. Is there the any other approaches for plotting this?

Comment: @MichaelE2, hi sir, what do you think about this question : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206901/plotting-ndsolve-function-in-complex-coordinates . Do you think it’s related?

Answer (score 2):

Generically there are 10 branches to choose for the value of `x'[t]` at a value for `x[t]` in the OP's differential equation

```
deOP =    x'[t] == (1 + (I x[t])^(9/5))^(1/2)
```

In this form, however, there will be discontinuous jumps in the value of `x'[t]` whenever `x[t]` crosses a branch cut of the differential equation `deOP`.  We can rationalize the equation to get the differential equation

```
deRat =   (x'[t]^2 - 1)^5 == (I x[t])^9
```

This form still has the intrinsic problem that there are generically 10 solutions for `x'[t]` for a given value of `x[t]`; however, there are not discontinuous jumps from crossing branch cuts in *Mathematica* functions.

Because of the square root (or equivalently, `x'[t]^2`), the roots come in pairs with opposite signs.  The pair of integral curves corresponding to such a pair of roots in fact trace the same path in the complex plane, but in opposite directions.  So generically through each value for `x[0]` pass five integral curves.

Theoretically the solutions may be computed with

```
NDSolve[{deRat, x[0] == x0}, x, {t, -8, 8}]
```

and indeed *Mathematica* tries to find all ten.  It is slow and it seems to have trouble staying on the right branch (there are corners in the plots, indicating a discontinuity in the derivative).

Another approach is to differentiate `deRat` to get a second order equation that is linear in `x''[t]`; then `x'[t]` will be integrated from the initial value and *Mathematica* never has to choose a branch.  The branch will be chosen by the choice of the initial value.  If the initial value for `x'[0]` is `dx0`, then the following code will find the solution:

```
NDSolveValue[{
   x''[t] == (x''[t] /. First@Solve[D[deRat, t], x''[t]]),
   x'[0]  == dx0,
   x[0]   == x0},
  x, {t, -100, 100}] &,
```

The five initial values for `x'[0]` that yield the distinct integral curves may be found with

```
Select[
 x'[0] /. Solve[{deRat /. t -> 0, x[0] == x0}, {x[0], x'[0]}],
 Re[#] > 0 &]
```

Below I'll get all the solutions by mapping `NDSolve` over the initial values for `x'[0]`. I'll integrate each solution until it exceeds a specified distance from the initial point `x[0]`, using `WhenEvent`.  To plot the solutions, it will be convenient to change how the interpolating functions extrapolate, since each solution will have a different domain.
The accepted answer to
[What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4/28341#28341)
shows what parts of an `InterpolatingFunction` to modify to change the default extrapolation behavior.  We can change the value returned by the `InterpolatingFunction` to `Indeterminate`; then `ParametricPlot` simply does not plot a point when the input `t` is outside of the domain.  The function `doNotExtrapolate` alters an `InterpolatingFunction` in this way.

Here is the complete code:

```
ClearAll[x, t, doNotExtrapolate];
doNotExtrapolate[if_InterpolatingFunction] :=
  ReplacePart[if, {
    {2, 10} -> (Indeterminate &),      (* Extrapolation Handler *)
    {2, 2} -> 6                        (* Warning -> False *)
    }];


deOP = x'[t] == (1 + (I x[t])^(9/5))^(1/2);
deRat = (x'[t]^2 - 1)^5 == (I x[t])^9;

x0 = -9877/10000 + I  1563/10000;
plotradius = 10;
dx0All = SortBy[
   Select[
    x'[0] /. Solve[{deRat /. t -> 0, x[0] == x0}, {x[0], x'[0]}],
    Re[#] > 0 &],
   Arg[N[#]] &];

xAll = Map[
    NDSolveValue[{
       x''[t] == (x''[t] /. First@Solve[D[deRat, t], x''[t]]),
       x'[0]  == #,
       x[0]   == x0,
       WhenEvent[Abs[x[t] - x0] > plotradius, "StopIntegration"]},
      x, {t, -100, 100}] &,
    dx0All
    ] /. if_InterpolatingFunction :> doNotExtrapolate[if];
```

Output:

```
GraphicsRow @ Table[
  With[{dx = plotradius/n, plotctr = {-0.9877, 0.1563}},
   ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[#[t]], Im[#[t]]} & /@ xAll], 
    Evaluate[{t}~Join~Through[{Min, Max}[Through[xAll["Domain"]]]]], 
    PlotRange -> (plotctr + {{-dx, dx}, {-dx, dx}}), 
    AspectRatio -> 1]
   ],
  {n, {1, 4, 50}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is very detailed and wonderful! Thanks!

Comment: @user14782 You're welcome!

Comment: Mathematica should add this as an example officially. Wonderful!